# Is inverted Japanese style curve persistent when negative rates are real / market - observed?

Tags: risk-models, negative, interest, rates

Are the inverted (Japanese style) governmental yield curves being a sign a recession/credit risk or should they be modelled as being due to a  lack of liquidity? (...with such curves evolving into a normally/positively-shaped yield curve, having more negative values for shorter horizons)

Comment: The reason no one has answered this question is that it contains too many extraneous details.  You need to simplify it.

Comment: Thanks @John. Could you give your opinion now ?

Comment: To be honest, I still don't understand what you're asking. I doubt you'll see a significant yield curve inversion when the short-term yield is kept at 0%. I just pulled on the Japanese curve on BB and saw inversion at the end of 1990 when rates were high, but nothing recent.

Comment: @John, I do not know how to add pictures to this forum, but this type of curve is what I mean (except that it is also exsting for bond yields): http://www.creditwritedowns.com/2012/06/the-us-tips-curve-has-become-inverted.html

Comment: This is a site with real-time governmental bonds (for Switzerland): http://www.forexpros.com/rates-bonds/switzerland-government-bonds?maturity_from=10&maturity_to=290

Comment: I think its important to draw attention to the fact that the curve in the linked is for inflation linked securities.

Answer (score 1):

1) JPY yield curve is currently upward sloping, not inverted...

2) Empirically, an upward sloping yield curve predicts recessions, not an inverted one. See this famous paper http://newyorkfed.org/research/current_issues/ci2-7.pdf

Comment: Thank you a lot for the article-link @haginile.  I'll edit the question, as you pointed on the June14 JPY curve. My question is about the JPY curve/inverted style, in general: will real market negative rates become more negative in1 year, and then inflect to positive values, or will they grow in magnitude and "stay" negative?